# The standard directory structure of a simple Website

Tags: html

I want to make a simple website with some pages. The index.html and some other pages like a project, contact, about us,...

Now, what's the best directory structure for SEO (I don't use WordPress):

1. index.html and the other files in the same directory
2. Only the index.html in the root directory and the other files in subdirectories like domainname/projects/ or domain/aboutus/

For the second case, how do I name the files? For Example: domain/projects/projects.html or domain/projects/index.html

Comment: If you don't use Wordpress, why did you tag your question with `wordpress`?